# Sharepoint 2010 workflow connect to external web service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am looking for simplest way to call an external web service from Sharepoint 2010 workflow.

I am thinking about calling external web service (I need to pass a couple of files for processing once they are uploaded to SharePoint list) programmatically.

but I don't know how to fire such action as a step in a workflow. I have access both to Sharepoint Designer and InfoPath.